# iOS Background Audio Icon

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios, core-audio, audioqueueservices

I've followed the API Docs and WWDC Videos exactly, to play audio in the background via an Audio Session (using the AudioQueue services). It all works just fine, but there is no "Play" indicator displayed in the Status Bar.

Do i have to set this separately or is it a Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was done by the Audio Session:

```
// before instantiating the playback audio queue object, 
//  set the audio session category
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty (
                         kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                         sizeof (sessionCategory),
                         &sessionCategory
                         );

// activate the audio session immmediately before playback starts
AudioSessionSetActive (true);
```

Comment: As i mentioned above, I already did all those steps Apple says you should do. And it works, but there is no icon! That's the problem.

Comment: How do you do audio recording in the background?